# Difference between $\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$\mathbb Z^+$ stands for the Positive Integers: $\{1,2,3,4,5\dots\}$

$\mathbb N$ stands for the Natural Numbers: $\{1,2,3,4,5\dots\}$

So what is the difference between $\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Many people (myself included) would use $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$.

Comment: Many people (myself included) would consider Bongers weird to do that.  But he is right.  The difference would otherwise be, in my mind at least, that $\Bbb Z^+$ supposes that there is the ambient space $\Bbb Z$ that it sits inside of, whereas $\Bbb N$ stands on its own (by default).  It's like saying "vector subspace" instead of just "vector space".  A subspace is a vector space in its own right, but by specifically invoking the "sub" you are indicating that there is a larger object of potential relevance that this thing is inside of.  Practically speaking, no difference, though.

Comment: @zibadawa: Many people would like to say that a set is finite if the number of elements it has is a natural number. If zero is not a natural number, the empty set is not finite. What is it, then?

Comment: It's a special case you make a separate definition for.  Alternatively, you can always add one more element to a set and then apply your definition.  Or create a different definition entirely. Et cetera.  The fact that annoying $0$ cases like this pop up fairly frequently is why Bongers is correct.

Comment: For now it's rare that the terminology *positive* is ambiguous, so instead of natural numbers, I would rather say *positive* integers, or *nonnegative* integers, though Bourbaki used the terminology *positive* as *nonnegative*.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I personally like my monoids to have unit elements, so I vote for $\mathbb N$ to include $0$. What is your reason to find that weird?

Comment: @zibadawa: When "the special case" is the common case, I don't see the issue with including $0$ in $\Bbb N$. Clearly you are not familiar with set theory (or you wouldn't have claimed that $0$ is not a natural number, and that it is weird to do that), so I don't see why you are so definitive in your decision that set theorists should use cumbersome definitions so often, rather than include $0$ in the natural numbers.

Comment: I'm assuming that when the OP says "difference," he or she is not referring to set difference. :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, obviously we can assert many things that are blindly accusatory and not very helpful at all.  There are just as many cases where starting at 1 is more natural than starting at 0, and if you have 0 in your natural numbers then you have to adjust your proofs because they can no longer use phrases like "for all natural numbers".  The literature is replete with both uses, and no one definition is commonly agreed upon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers), the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are sometimes thought of as the positive integers $\mathbb{Z}^+=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ or as the non-negative integers $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.  That is why mathematicians should always clearly define what they mean by natural numbers at the start.